# GWT DisclourePanel

Tags: gwt, casting, panel

I have got a DisclourePanel with a button on it. But when I call button.getParent()
I always get a SimplePanel. With other Panel like VerticalPanel it works.
Does Anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

DisclosurePanel extends type Composite meaning it is a widget that can be composed of many widgets. It consists of a header and a SimplePanel both stacked in a VerticalPanel. Any content you give it, is placed in this SimplePanel, in your case a button, thus SimplePanel is returned by `getParent()`